# I cant access my authenthicator app so ı cant access my microsoft work account

Tags: microsoft-account

I am trying to log in to my Microsoft account but the thing is it wants me to access my authenticator app however, even that ı access it ı can never get the notification that Microsoft sent. Also ı dont see any code from the authenticator that ı can write to microsoft so ı can enter. Right now ı even cant access my authenticator so what should ı do?

When ı enter my password it directs me to 2 options: approve the notification sent to my authenticator and write the code from my authenticator app. However, even ı tried several times ı could never pass this step and access my account. I even tried to reset my password several times but that also didn't work.